# node js crashing, saying a variable is undefined, when it isnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, async-await, crash

Here is my GET request handler, to render a page:

```
app.get("/:band", async (req, res) => {
   const page = req.params.band;
   try {
   const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM artists");
   const artistData = result.rows;
   const band = artistData.findIndex((info) => info.onewordid === page);
   const bandInfo = artistData[band];
   console.log(bandInfo);
   const articlesresult = await db.query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE artist_id = $1", 
    [bandInfo.id]);
   res.render("artistpage.ejs", {
    artistinfo: bandInfo,
    data: artistData,
    articles: articlesresult.rows,
   });
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```

An example band object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'The Rolling Stones',
  picadress: 'backgroundpic2.jpeg',
  onewordid: 'stones'
}
```

The error/output:

```
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at file:///Users/admin/Downloads/Web%20development%20Project/Backend/Blog%20Project%20Styling/index.js:83:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Why can I console log this, but I get bandInfo.id as "undefined"?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, I cleaned up your question a little to make it more readable you should make sure I did not alter anything meaningful. second, could you add an example of the GET request you are making which would match the sample JSON/bandInfo object you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Try `bandInfo[0].id` instead of `bandInfo.id` in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these four lines of code.

```
   const artistData = result.rows;
   const band = artistData.findIndex((info) => info.onewordid === page);
   const bandInfo = artistData[band];
   console.log(bandInfo);
```

I believe the `console.log(...)` statement is printing `undefined` into your output, just before the error information is printed into your output.

I also believe the third line assigning to `bandInfo` is actually incorrectly indexing into `artistData`, because `artistData` is a reference to `result.rows`.

Line 3 which assigns to `band` is already looking up the target object/row from the results, so you shouldn't need to re-index the rows a second time.

Consider simplifying your code as follows:

```
   const bandInfo = result.rows.findIndex((row) => row.onewordid === req.params.band);
   console.log(bandInfo);
```

In this version of the code you do not need `page` nor `artistData`, these temporary assignments meant to simplify the code actually increase complexity. That's not a solution to your problem, however. The solution here is to perform the lookup (using `findIndex(...)`) and assign it directly to `bandInfo`.

As a debugging aid, before making any other changes, you could change the `console.log(...)` to give yourself better information:

```
  console.log({
    page: page,
    band: band,
    bandInfo: bandInfo
  });
```

Lastly, how to interpret this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

This means that while trying to read the property `id` the parent reference was undefined. Given your code, this expression would be the only which could be the problem: `bandInfo.id`, and again, the sample logging you provided for `console.log(bandInfo)` is printing `undefined` before `console.log(err)` prints the error information.

Good luck!

Comment: as an aside, querying the entire `artists` table and performing a lookup in-code will be slower than filtering results within the SQL statement. ie: `await db.query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE onewordid = $1", [req.params.band])` -- since you're new to StackOverflow, once your code is working, you may find it useful to use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for insights on how to improve your code.